# KnockoutJs: What are the types of Event available on knockoutJs

Tags: knockout.js

I want to implement a scroll even in knockoutJS, but just noticed this event type is not in their documentation, but i saw this event `event: { scroll: scrolled }"` used in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748448/knockout-virtual-scrolling-binding) , so my question now is what other events are available, as the documentation doesn't state all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html):

> The `event` binding allows you to add an event handler for a specified event so that your chosen JavaScript function will be invoked when that event is triggered for the associated DOM element. **This can be used to bind to any event**, such as `keypress`, `mouseover` or `mouseout`.

(emphasis mine).

So you can hook it up to any standard event.